# Python3 Tkinter - Write input (y) to console for subprocess

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, input, tkinter

I've been looking around for an answer to my problem but have been unlucky. I would like for the answer to work with native python and hopefully be simple.

My problem is that I'm using subprocess in my tkinter application, but one of the commands require you to write Y/N to be sure you want to proceed with the action.

So I'm looking for a way to write y into the terminal when a message like this appears:
Are you sure you want to continue? (y/N)

I've tried by running subprocess.run("y") but that doesn't seem to work.

I'm testing this on Debian Linux and to call the command that asks if I want to proceed, is subprocess.getoutput() so that I can check for errors.

***CODE***

```
class RemovePublicKeyDialog:
def __init__(self, parent):
    top = self.top = Toplevel(parent)

    Label(top, text="Who to remove?").pack()

    self.e = Entry(top)
    self.e.pack(padx=5)

    b = Button(top, text="REMOVE", command=self.ok)
    b.pack(pady=5)

def ok(self):
    #print("value is " + self.e.get())
    key = self.e.get()
    cmd = subprocess.getoutput("gpg --delete-keys " + key)
    print(cmd)
    if ("key \"" + key + "\" not found" in cmd):
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "No such public key.")
    elif ("Delete this key from keyring?" in cmd):
        #subprocess.run("echo 'y'")
        messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Public key \"" + key + "\" deleted from keyring.")
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Unknown error, did you input a key?")

    self.top.destroy()
```

This is the "main" code, everything works but it's just that I need to input Y to get it to proceed.

Comment: Depending on the command, you might be able to supply a flag that causes it to skip confirmations from the user, such as `--no-confirm`.

Comment: Do you just want to pop up a message to ask 'yes' & 'no', and take an action depending on which one is pressed?

Comment: For certain commands the -y flag do what you need, for example: apt-get -y install [packagename]. Checkout your command manual (man command)

Comment: Please add some code to your question. - [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have now tried to check if there is any such options but doesn't seem to be (looked through help file and searched online), -y doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Many command line utilities have a flag that automatically answers yes to any prompts - if you have access to the source code of your particular command, adding such a flag if it doesn't have one (or simply making a custom version that never prompts) may be the easiest solution.  Some commands automatically do this if not run directly from a terminal - are you sure that this is even a problem?

If you know that there will be a single prompt, you could try:
    `subprocess.run("echo y | your-command", shell=True)`

If there may be multiple prompts, you'd have to use one of the more complex options in the subprocess module, reading and parsing the command output to know when a reply is needed.

Comment: That's probably true that that would be the easiest solution, but I'm trying to do this so it just runs if I took it over to another system. And sadly the echo y and command thing did not work.